# setTimeout in jQuery.each not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, settimeout

I wanna imitate the menu item animation of [this site](http://y.co)

here's the key code I write to  make the animation:

```
li{transition:transform 600ms}
li.animated{transform:translateY(20px)}

/* Javascript */
  $('nav ul li').each(function(i){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('ul li').addClass('animated');
    },400*i)
  })
```

But it doesn't work, in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yqynyL2n/2/), the 4 items are being translated together, not "timeoutted" at all; strangely, in my actual site, the codes seem to be more broken, the class wasn't added at all. I inspected the code of my site and fiddle again, but I couldn't find where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `this` to target each elements individually,

```
  $('ul li').each(function(i){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $(this).addClass('animated');
    }.bind(this),400*i)
  });
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/yqynyL2n/4/)

Or you can use arrow function to fix this,

```
  $('ul li').each(function(i){
    setTimeout(()=>{
      $(this).addClass('animated');
    },400*i)
  });
```

Comment: ewww... that's a typo, in my actual site, I was using 'this', but not the "bind",so why `bind`?

Comment: I guess if not `bind`, when `$(this).addClass` is called, the `this` is probably `window`, right?

Comment: @shenkwen Inside setTimeout, the this will point to the window. So if you want to target the outside context, you have to use either bind or arrow function. This will be helpful not only for your problem but for many situations.

Comment: +1 for arrow function, I saw that before, didn't understand and didn't know how to search it.
I apply your solution to my site http://w.nycweb.io, it works. However strangely the menu items are not moving evenly, any clue why?

Comment: @shenkwen It is working fine here. https://jsfiddle.net/yqynyL2n/6/ . In your website also, it is moving fine. I don't understand your problem. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: the 3rd item is moving too soon after the 2nd item starts moving. actually they are moving almost together, while others you can see obvious differences

Comment: @shenkwen I can't see such behavior here. I am using chrome. There is no chance for that to happen with our code. Are you sure that you have same css rules for all of those elements?

Comment: hmm.... I use chrome too. Actually I just checked and it works fine with firefox and other browsers. As to chrome, it is like this: http://w.nycweb.io/o.mp4. It seems having to with cache, I cleared browser data, and it is still like this, this worths another question I guess.. I would appreciate if you could give me some clue so that I can better write the question.

Comment: @shenkwen Yes I too think that you have to ask a new question for this. since that is out of context from your initial problem. And creation of new question will get you more attention towards that.

Comment: I think the problem is due to setTimeout gets messed up when other parts of the page is loading(I didn't put it in document ready function). Anyway, I find a less JSy way to do the animation but encountered some cross-browser problem. You might want to check this question started by me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530026/transition-delay-property-in-non-chrome-browser

Answer (score 3):

You can use the second parameter from the .each method to determine the element. Like:

```
$('.inOrder').click(function(){
  $('ul li').each(function(i, ele){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $(ele).addClass('animated');
    },400*i);
  })
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2pgf76vx/2/